# How do I use a onItemLongClickListener in my Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am using the `ItemClickSupport` class and I would like to use their long click listener but how do I know if it has been clicked long? Sadly I didn't find any examples using this.

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView3).setOnItemLongClickListener { recyclerView, position, v -> true }
```

How do I check if it is true? And how do I get the position it has been clicked at?

ItemClickSupport.java: [gist](https://gist.github.com/shayousefi/2d61827ea4ca68ab3d02)

```
/**
 * A class that adds item click support to a {@link RecyclerView}.
 *
 * @author Hugo Visser
 * @see <a href="http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/">
 * Getting your clicks on RecyclerView</a>
 */
public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener;

    private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) {
                final int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                final long id = recyclerView.getChildItemId(v);
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(recyclerView, v, position, id);
            }
        }
    };

    private View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (itemLongClickListener != null) {
                final int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                final long id = recyclerView.getChildItemId(v);
                return itemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(recyclerView, v, position, id);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener attachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            }

            if (itemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(null);
            }

            if (itemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            }
        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(@NonNull RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
            support.attach(view);
        } else {
            Log.w("RecyclerView already has ItemClickSupport.");
        }
        return support;
    }

    private void attach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        view.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(attachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(@NonNull RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        } else {
            Log.w("RecyclerView does not have ItemClickSupport.");
        }
        return support;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(attachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
        itemClickListener = null;
        itemLongClickListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return The callback to be invoked when an item in the {@link RecyclerView}
     * has been clicked, or {@code null} if no callback has been set.
     */
    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return itemClickListener;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an item in the
     * {@link RecyclerView} has been clicked.
     *
     * @param listener callback that will be invoked
     */
    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        itemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return The callback to be invoked when an item in the {@link RecyclerView}
     * has been clicked and held, or {@code null} if no callback has been set.
     */
    public OnItemLongClickListener getOnItemLongClickListener() {
        return itemLongClickListener;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an item in the
     * {@link RecyclerView} has been clicked and held.
     *
     * @param listener callback that will be invoked
     */
    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        itemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an item in the
     * {@link RecyclerView} has been clicked.
     */
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        /**
         * Callback method to be invoked when an item in the {@code RecyclerView}
         * has been clicked.
         *
         * @param parent   {@code RecyclerView} where the click happened
         * @param view     view within the {@code RecyclerView} that was clicked
         * @param position position of the view in the adapter
         * @param id       row ID of the item that was clicked
         */
        void onItemClick(RecyclerView parent, View view, int position, long id);
    }

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an item in the
     * {@link RecyclerView} has been clicked and held.
     */
    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {
        /**
         * Callback method to be invoked when an item in the {@code RecyclerView}
         * has been clicked and held.
         *
         * @param parent   {@code RecyclerView} where the click happened
         * @param view     view within the {@code RecyclerView} that was clicked
         * @param position position of the view in the adapter
         * @param id       row ID of the item that was clicked
         * @return {@code true} if the callback consumed the long click; {@code false} otherwise.
         */
        boolean onItemLongClick(RecyclerView parent, View view, int position, long id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `{recyclerView, position, v -> true}`,  `recyclerView, position, v` are the arguments to your `onItemLongClick` callback. You would use it like this:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView3).setOnItemLongClickListener { recyclerView, view, position, id ->
    // Use position here

    true // False if not consumed
}
```

***Edit:***

If `OnItemLongClickListener` is a Kotlin interface you would use it like this:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView3).setOnItemLongClickListener(object: ItemClickSupport.OnItemLongClickListener {
    override fun onItemLongClick(parent: RecyclerView, view: View, position: Int, id: Long): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
})
```

Comment: It's not allowed to do a return inside there and I also get this: `Error:(120, 19) Cannot access 'TAG': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'AppCompatActivity'`

Comment: Check edited answer. Also the Log statement was just to illustrate you could use the position argument

Comment: Sorry maybe I seem very dumb now but how do I check if it has been long pressed to do something with it? `if(recyclerView3.onLongClick == true){}`

Comment: When the user long clicks any item, this method is called by `ItemClickSupport`. So you would do what you need to inside this lambda.

Comment: `ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView3).setOnItemLongClickListener { recyclerView, view, position, id ->
   Toast.makeText(context, "Its a long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    true // False if not consumed
}` Like this? but if I do it I get this error `Error:(117, 74) Type mismatch: inferred type is (???, ???, ???, ???) -> Boolean but ItemClickSupport.OnItemLongClickListener! was expected`

Comment: Sorry, please check the edited answer its `ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView3).OnItemLongClickListener` not `ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView3).setOnItemLongClickListener`

Comment: So your `ItemClickSupport` is it a java class or a kotlin class?

Comment: its a java class but it works with the onClick thing that shouldnt matter should it?

Comment: If `OnItemLongClickListener` was a kotlin interface then you can't use it like a lambda and would have to create an anonymous object. But you say it is a java interface. can you share your version of `ItemClickSupport` ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nesquena/231e356f372f214c4fe6 oh now I get what you mean but how can I make it not be lambda? I think I turned on automatic translation to kotlin

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working I get this error: `Error:(119, 74) Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onItemLongClicked(recyclerView: RecyclerView!, position: Int, v: View!): Boolean defined in abyte.fitness.fitnessbyte.ItemClickSupport.OnItemLongClickListener`

Comment: Ohh we are referring two different version of the same interface. My method has different parameters than yours. Do one thing type in : https://gist.github.com/VeneetReddyK/c67aea42673b763fc120b0b4e5c78438 and press alt + enter(cursor on the error)  and click implement methods.